# Create jobs and execute them in jenkins using REST

Tags: rest, wcf, jenkins, jenkins-api

I am trying to create a WCF REST client that will communicate to Jenkins and create a job from an XML file and then build the job. My understanding is that you can do that with Jenkins.

Can some one please provide some commands that you can type on a browser's address bar to create and build jobs? ie: `http:localhost/jenkins/createItem?name=TESTJOB` something along those lines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the [Jenkins API Wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) (including the comments at the end).  You can fill in the gaps using the documentation provided by Jenkins itself; for example, `http://JENKINS_HOST/api` will give you the URL for creating a job and `http://JENKINS_HOST/job/JOBNAME/api` will give you the URL to trigger a build.

I highly recommend avoiding the custom creation of job configuration XML files and looking at something like the [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) instead.  This gives you a nice Groovy-based DSL to create jobs programmatically - much more concise and less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a bit but I was finally able to figure it out. I just wish their API wiki page was more informative and with better examples.

Answer (score 26):

Usually, when parsing through the documentation, it can take one or two days.  It is helpful to be able to access code or curl commands to get you up and running in one hour.  That is my objective with a lot of third party software.

See the post at http://scottizu.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/getting-started-with-the-jenkins-api/ which lists several of the curl commands.  You will have to replace my.jenkins.com (ie JENKINS_HOST) with the your own url.

To create a job, for instance, try:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d "<project><builders/><publishers/><buildWrappers/></project>" "http://JENKINS_HOST/createItem?name=AA_TEST_JOB2"
```

This uses a generic config.  You can also download a config from a manually created job and then use that as a template.

```
curl "http://JENKINS_HOST/job/MY_JOB_NAME/config.xml" > config.xml
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d @config.xml "http://JENKINS_HOST/createItem?name=AA_TEST_JOB3"
```

To execute the job (and set string parameters), use:

```
curl "http://JENKINS_HOST/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build"
curl "http://JENKINS_HOST/job/MY_JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER0=VALUE0&PARAMETER1=VALUE1"
```

Comment: do you know how to write `-d "<project><builders/><publishers/><buildWrappers/></project>"` in postman?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to a GIST - https://gist.github.com/stuart-warren/7786892

> Check if job exists

```
curl -XGET 'http://jenkins/checkJobName?value=yourJobFolderName' --user user.name:YourAPIToken
```

> With folder plugin

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://jenkins/job/FolderName/createItem?name=yourJobName' --data-binary @config.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml" --user user.name:YourAPIToken
```

> Without folder plugin

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://jenkins/createItem?name=yourJobName' --data-binary @config.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml" --user user.name:YourAPIToken
```

> Create folder

```
curl -XPOST 'http://jenkins/createItem?name=FolderName&mode=com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder&from=&json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22FolderName%22%2C%22mode%22%3A%22com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder%22%2C%22from%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Submit%22%3A%22OK%22%7D&Submit=OK' --user user.name:YourAPIToken -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to  create a job into a view given the view exists.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d @build.xml "http://jenkins_host/view/viewName/createItem?name=itemName"
```

the build.xml filetemplate could be found in the root directory of a job's workspace

if you want to create a view:

```
curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml"  -d @view.xml "http://jenkins_host/createView?name=viewName"
```

the content of the file  view.xml could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hudson.model.ListView>
    <name>viewName</name>
    <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
    <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
    <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    <jobNames>
        <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
    </jobNames>
    <jobFilters/>
    <columns>
        <hudson.views.StatusColumn/>
        <hudson.views.WeatherColumn/>
        <hudson.views.JobColumn/>
        <hudson.views.LastSuccessColumn/>
        <hudson.views.LastFailureColumn/>
        <hudson.views.LastDurationColumn/>
        <hudson.views.BuildButtonColumn/>
    </columns>
</hudson.model.ListView>
```

and to check if a view exists:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" "http://jenkins_host/checkViewName?value=viewName"
```

to check if a job exists:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" "http://jenkins_host/checkJobName?value=jobName"
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a job:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d "<project><builders/><publishers/><buildWrappers/></project>" -u username: API_Token http://JENKINS_HOST/createItem?name=AA_TEST_JOB2
```

To build a job:

```
curl -X POST -u username:API_TOKEN http://JENKINS_HOST/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to make the same HTTP calls using the Python requests library, instead of CURL...

Download a job config:

```
import requests
auth = ("username", "api_token")
url = "http://" + JENKINS_HOST + "/job/" + JOB_NAME + "/config.xml"
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
open('config.xml', 'wt').write(response.text)
```

Create a new job using same config:

```
url = "http://" + JENKINS_HOST + "/createItem?name=" + NEW_JOB_NAME
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
data = response.text
response = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Omit `auth` parameter when not needed.