# Many instances of one java project at the same time using gradle and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, parallel-processing

I have an a single java project (let's say its name is PROJ) build in gradle and I wanted to run this project X times parallel, using Jenkins jobs. In addition, I would like to pass some parameters strictly to this project and somehow using it during project execution. How to do that?

**Example**

I have three Jenkins jobs, all executed at 1am:

- JOB1 is building a gradle project PROJ with parameter PAR=V1
- JOB2 is building a gradle project PROJ with parameter PAR=V2
- JOB3 is building a gradle project PROJ with parameter PAR=V3

Inside my java class I want to print the current value of the parameter PAR and the result should be as follows:

```
JOB1: Value of parameter PAR is V1
JOB2: Value of parameter PAR is V2
JOB3: Value of parameter PAR is V3
```

(of course due to the fact that tasks will be performed in parallel, messages could be in different order, e.g. V3, V1, V2)

**Alternatively**, is there a possibility that there can be only one job in Jenkins, but gradle has been configured to build project X times in parallel with different parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Jenkins parameterized builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991273/how-to-use-jenkins-parameterized-builds)

Comment: With Jenkins (even using parameterized build) I can run at the same time only as many processes as the node executors are defined (I exclude slaves). So if I wanted to run e.g. 15 instances of job at the same time, it would be impossible. Do gradle settings give this possibility?

Comment: But you can create new jobs "on the fly" through the jenkins API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909650/create-jobs-and-execute-them-in-jenkins-using-rest and https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API