# jenkinsapi python - trigger and track the job result

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-api

according to this question [jenkinsapi python - how to trigger and track the job result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643387/jenkinsapi-python-how-to-trigger-and-track-the-job-result), I should get the next build number and then track it,
this solution will fail when running in multi threading.
is there a way to cover this case also ? maybe by adding a uniq ID to the build ?